# Recognize this UDP protocol or data structure: x48 x65 "He"?

Tags: networking, udp, protocols

**These bytes start each data block with no changes in bytes**

```
00000000  48 65 01 01 00 00 00 00  d3 af 38 7a 5e 3b f8 1b   He...... ..8z^;..
```

**First 8 bytes do not change.  The next four bytes appear to be a counter.  The packages are not necessarily in the right order, according to this counter.**

```
00000010  17 fe fd 00 01 00 00 00  00 09 e8 00 92 f0 58 3b   ........ ......X;

00000020  2f a3 f1 dd ff 1e 3d 4d  9b ea d8 ef bd c2 ad cf   /.....=M ........

00000030  39 0e bc 8e b0 50 6d e3  c0 ce ed 94 0c 6e c3 e7   9....Pm. .....n..

00000040  ca bf a3 7d 62 2c 99 5a  22 40 e4 64 83 09 53 ba   ...}b,.Z "@.d..S.

00000050  42 e5 1d 85 09 2c 64 aa  f4 ae 01 76 89 d9 31 97   B....,d. ...v..1.

00000060  70 ef 90 91 94 01 72 89  de 34 3e 9b 2c d3 6d 64   p.....r. .4>.,.md

00000070  55 14 bc 76 e7 8b c2 3b  81 07 61 cd 99 f8 c7 d5   U..v...; ..a.....

00000080  b9 eb c3 02 e4 03 8d bc  b1 91 08 6e 91 5f 9e 1b   ........ ...n._..

00000090  58 a8 32 d9 f5 da d9 28  ec 05 87 cf 27 f1 74 dc   X.2....( ....'.t.

000000A0  30 94 aa b1 c9 5a b2 85  35 3e 2a 99 8b c8 2d      0....Z.. 5>*...-
```

**Data block has variable length.**

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I think this is OpenVPN traffic using a port other than default.  The 0x48 indicates it is P_DATA_V2.

Comment: "Custom Comment" from the 'Review' Queue, your Answer looks "just OK" to me, @Answerer, but the Qt itself from #OP looks pretty Low Quality to me, any chance you could add MORE Info to your Answer...?, or add a Comment to #OP asking them to improve the Quality of their Qt (not sure if you can do that, Rep=50 needed for Comments) or edit the Qt to improve its Qlt... [I'm New to this Review Queue myself...]

Comment: Oh...!, from the 'Review Queue', it was not visible/obvious that you (the Answerer) were answering your own Qt with your Solution, which is very nice to share..., but hum, again, your Qt to start with is "Low Quality", you would need to edit your Qt to improve its Qlt... OK, "good luck with that", the Qt/Thread will otherwise get automatically deleted in 30 days by some Site Cleaning Bot if you don't get a few Up-Votes on Qt and/or Answer...